# Inherit NLog WrapperTargetBase for synchronous logging

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Web Service and use NLog 4.7.0 for logging. I am currently using file logging and a filebeat to get the messages from the log files to ELK.

I want to create a wrapper target for my `FileTarget`. The actual purpose is to merge all logs for a single web request into a single log message, but this is probably beside the point.

I want to inherit from `NLog.Targets.Wrappers.WrapperTargetBase`, but the `Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)` method is sealed. Does this mean I can only use async logging for WrapperTargets?

Does this affect how I set up my logging configuration? Note that I am using configuration file, rather than configuration API, for config.

My existing `FileTarget` is like this:

````
"appFile": {
    "type": "File",
    "fileName": "c:\\wwwlogs\\MyWebApp\\Combined.log",
    "archiveFileName": "c:\\wwwlogs\\MyWebApp.Web\\archives\\Combined.{#}.log",
    "archiveEvery": "Day",
    "archiveNumbering": "Rolling",
    "maxArchiveFiles": "7",
    "layout": "${longdate}|${aspnet-request-ip}|${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}|${aspnet-user-identity}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
  }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options:

In all cases you need the attribute in your class:

```
[Target("MyWrapper", IsWrapper = true)]
```

#### WrapperTargetBase single item

When inheriting from WrapperTargetBase, your target could be async, but it also works sync. You need some more code to handle it.

1. Inherit from WrapperTargetBase
2. override the `protected override void Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)`
3. Write to target with `WrappedTarget.WriteAsyncLogEvent(logEvent);`

When not using `WriteAsyncLogEvent`, please not you should call `logEvent.Continuation` (with exception or null)

#### WrapperTargetBase  grouped

Writing events grouped

1. Inherit from WrapperTargetBase
2. override  `protected override void Write(IList<AsyncLogEventInfo> logEvents)`
3. Write with a loop or use `AsyncHelpers`

#### Target

Another option is to `Inherit` from Target. This is easier approach, but it doesn't work with Async out of the box.
Because you have `[Target("MyWrapper", IsWrapper = true)]`, this works. You need this in your class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the target that is wrapped by this target.
/// </summary>
[RequiredParameter]
public Target WrappedTarget { get; set; }
```